# codeigniter and active record ordering db result

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$pag = $this->db->get('articles', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));         
$data['records'] = $pag->result();
```

I already tried with

```
$pag = $this->db->get('articles', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));         
$this->db->order_by('published', 'ASC');
$data['records'] = $pag->result();
```

either use `ASC` or `desc` I dont see any change.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that: you execute the query before you ask to order it.
Order before and then execute the query
When you make: `db->get` you execute the query, if you have a where condition or an order condition you have to put it before the get command.
Try this

```
$this->db->order_by('published', 'ASC');
$pag = $this->db->get('articles', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));  
$data['records'] = $pag->result();
```

[**DOCUMENTATION**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Move the order_by statement to top.

```
$this->db->order_by('published', 'ASC');
$pag = $this->db->get('articles', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));         
$data['records'] = $pag->result();
```